# Handling rent debt in California

Tags: united-states, debt, california, rent, covid-19

Due to the pandemic, I was unable to pay rent for my apartment complex that I have now moved out of. I do not have the money to pay this debt because I was unemployed because of the pandemic. Additionally, I am below median income.

Are there options to assist in payment? How can I best handle my debt?

Comment: That's like asking, "How can I make money?". Here's a strategy for you: (1) work for pay (2) spend less than you receive for working (3) use the money you save to pay down the debt.

Comment: Were you evicted, or did you voluntarily move out?  Not sure, but this *could* affect your ability to apply for any kind of rent relief under the stimulus bills, I think.

Comment: @SRiverNet I was in a lease that the apartment complex wouldn’t break. So I had no option other than to stay in the lease, rack up debt, and wait until the evicted me.

Answer (score 7):

Part of the trillions in stimulus was set aside for rent assistance. In California you need to apply through this site:
https://housing.ca.gov/covid_rr/

> If one or more individuals in your household meet all of the
> following, you are eligible to apply:
>
> 1. Have qualified for unemployment benefits or experienced a reduction in
>    household income, incurred significant costs, or experienced other
>    financial hardship due to COVID–19; and
> 2. Demonstrate a risk of
>    experiencing homelessness or housing instability, which may include:
>
>    - a past-due utility or rent notice or eviction notice;
>    - unsafe or unhealthy living conditions; or
>    - any other evidence of such risk, as determined by the program
> 3. Have a household income that is not more
>    than 80% of the Area Median Income

If you qualify your landlord will have to waive 20% of unpaid rent in order to get 80% of the unpaid rent via the program (up to certain program limits and depending on availability of funds, it seems).

This seems to be very similar to Colorado's implementation, so I'd imagine most states have similar/identical criteria. Anyone in similar need should just search "covid rent assistance" + their state

Comment: "If you qualify your landlord will have to waive 20% of unpaid rent" The landlord does not have to. It is voluntary. By agreeing to waive 20% of unpaid rent, the landlord receives 80% via the program. But the landlord doesn't have to agree to do this. If the landlord does not agree, I believe that the renter may receive 25% via the program, but the the amount owed to the landlord would otherwise still be the same.

Comment: @user102008 In order to get the 80% they have to waive 20%, altered wording slightly since that was perhaps not clear enough, good note about the landlord not choosing to participate, as a landlord I never viewed that as a reasonable approach.

Comment: @Hart, The complication here to using any kind of rent relief from the stimulus bills is that the OP says they've already moved out of the apartment.  I don't recall seeing anything about being able to receive assistance for rents due for a dwelling you no longer occupy.  Am I mistaken on this?

Comment: @SRiverNet You're speculating that they maybe forgot to list a pretty significant requirement for eligibility? I've never heard of that being an issue so my assumption is that it is not, but I don't have firsthand experience all my tenants were able to pay rent throughout, luckily.

Comment: Reading the reqs, it almost seems implied you have to be in occupancy, since it says the legislative intent is to provide assistance to people "at risk of eviction", hence if one has already vacated then this wouldn't apply. I was curious from your experience as a landlord and familiarity with this. I am not a landlord nor do I know the details of the program, so I was seeking your input. (smile) And frankly, as rushed as the policy process was, nothing would surprise me about what might have been left out.

Comment: That's fair, I don't expect they would punish people who took steps to minimize the harm by moving in with family/friends etc, and many leases would have ended before the program even began taking applications, so I'm pretty confident current occupancy is not a requirement, perhaps OP will update on their experience with the program.

Comment: All of the relief programs for the city of San Diego require that you still have to be living at the place you have back rent for. I moved out and stayed with a friend until I could get a handle of things. Now I’m in a spot paying rent and I am trying to deal with the rent I couldn’t pay from Last April- June. I was just curious to know if anyone knew if there were programs that helped with that.

Comment: @Fay Did you talk to your landlord about them applying for relief under the program? Also, is there a difference between county/state programs?

Answer (score 1):

Hart CO, as usual, provided a concise answer to your specific question.  However there were some stipulations that came up in the comments that may prevent you from qualifying.

In those cases, follow the typical advice for debt that is difficult to impossible to pay:

1. Let the item go to collections
2. Save up cash to pay off the collection
3. When the collections company contacts you say I have $400 cash (or whatever), I will send that to you if I get it in writing that this loan is satisfied and considered paid off.
4. Never make arrangements for payments or give access to your checking account.  Send the payment by Visa gift card or money order **once the letter is received**.
5. If they say no, let them contact you next month and offer a bit more money.

Please note that step 3 assumes you owe something on the order of $5,000 or more.

The landlords are idiots if they do not waive 20-25% of rent owed in order to get the remainder from the government.  Doing it the typical way they are unlikely to recover 10%.

Comment: I may ask this as separate question but why "give access to your checking account. ". Why mo vs check?

Comment: @paulj A check is okay.  Direct debit will result in them taking much more funds then what you agreed upon.  Debt collectors are scum.